# replace for loop with dplyr

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, pipe

I would like to replace this simple for loop with a `dplyr` option:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(7,3), rep(8,3), rep(9,3)), visit= c(rep(c(0, 180, 360),3)), value = c("Poor", NA, "High", "High", NA, "High", NA, "Poor", "Poor") )

vec <- sum(!is.na(df$value)[df$visit==0])

for (i in seq(180, 360, 180)) {
      tmp <- sum(!is.na(df$value)[df$visit==i])
      vec <- c(vec, tmp)
 }
```

to obtain the vector of lengths where 'value' is not missing, for each 'visit' `i`:

```
 vec
[1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: `tapply(!is.na(df$value), df$visit, sum)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `dplyr` approach would be `group_by` your `visit` column, then `sum` up `value` that is not `NA`.

If you wish you have a dataframe instead of a vector, just ignore `pull(vec)`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(visit) %>% 
  summarize(vec = sum(!is.na(value))) %>% 
  pull(vec)

[1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I have 'vec' as an object in the global environment?

Comment: @Sabri. `vec <- df %>% group_by(visit) %>% summarize(vec = sum(!is.na(value))) %>% pull(vec)`